# Error: "Missing initializer in const declaration" plaid api create link token

Tags: node.js, typescript, plaid

I'm trying to setup the plaid api in my node.js code and I need to be able to make a request for the `create_link_token`. The sample code from their docs is as follows:

```
const request: LinkTokenCreateRequest = {
  user: {
    client_user_id: 'user-id',
  },
  client_name: 'Plaid Test App',
  products: ['auth', 'transactions'],
  country_codes: ['US'],
  language: 'en',
  webhook: 'https://sample-web-hook.com',
  redirect_uri: 'https://domainname.com/oauth-page.html',
  account_filters: {
    depository: {
      account_subtypes: ['DepositoryAccountSubtype.Checking, DepositoryAccountSubtype.Savings'],
    },
  },
};
try {
  const response = await plaidClient.linkTokenCreate(request);
  const linkToken = response.data.link_token;
} catch (error) {
  // handle error
}
```

my code is:

```
app.post('/api/create_link_token', async (req, res, next) => {
  const request: LinkTokenCreateRequest = {
    user: {
      client_user_id: 'user-id',
    },
    client_name: 'Plaid Test App',
    products: ['auth', 'transactions'],
    country_codes: ['US'],
    language: 'en',
    webhook: 'https://sample-web-hook.com',
    redirect_uri: 'https://domainname.com/oauth-page.html',
    account_filters: {
      depository: {
        account_subtypes: ['DepositoryAccountSubtype.Checking, DepositoryAccountSubtype.Savings'],
      },
    },
  };
  try {
    const response = await plaidClient.linkTokenCreate(request);
    const linkToken = response.data.link_token;
  } catch(e) {
    handleError(e);
  }
});
```

Right off the bat I get the error: `'LinkTokenCreateRequest' refers to a value, but is being used as a type here. Did you mean 'typeof LinkTokenCreateRequest'?ts(2749)` as a red underline underneath `LinkTokenCreateRequest`. *Side note I've never used TS before this, but I believe I have to use it on this project because some of their components require it.* If I do as they suggest and change it to `typeof LinkTokenCreateRequest = {...` then the red underline error goes away, however upon starting the server I get the error:

```
const request: typeof LinkTokenCreateRequest = {
      ^^^^^^^
SyntaxError: Missing initializer in const declaration
```

I've very confused as to how I can make this work so any suggestions would be much appreciated.

Comment: Sounds like it's being executed as JS, and not being compiled as TS - that's the same error you get when running the code in JS

Comment: Ok, I don't have a tsconfig.json file in my project (unsure if that matters or not) or any mention of typescript in my package.json. When I get home I'll lookup the steps to initializing a ts project and follow them. If that resolves the issue I'll make an edit to this post. 
Thanks!